# User cannot mail themself via Exchange

Tags: email, exchange-server-2010

We currently experience the problem that a user cannot send a mail to herself.
She get the error that she's not allowed to send e-mails from this address.

(You are not allowed to send on behalf of this user...)

Her e-mail address is AAA@domain.com.
(From AAA@domain.com to AAA@domain.com)

She can:

- Send e-mails internally
- Send e-mails externally
- Receive internal e-mails
- Receive external e-mails

We make use of Office 2016 and Exchange 2010 14.03.0399.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the local address book was corrupt. 
Disabled addressbook, deleted the local file and enabled it again.

This solved the issue